# Regex Pattern Matching .Net

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying the match the following possible scenarios. They are all phone numbers but they can be from anywhere in the world.

- "92134"
- "+234234"
- "-234234"
- "234(234)"
- "(559) 559-5591 ext123"
- "(559)    559-5591 EXT123"
- "(559) 559-5591 Ext123"
- "(559) 559-5591 x123"
- "(559)    559-5591 X123"
- "416.123.4567"

Now I'm not limiting the number of digits or anything but the key problems are the following.

Allow:

- '()', '-', '.' anywhere in the string... start end e.t.c
- '+' as the first character (Doesn't need to be though)
- 'ext', 'Ex't, 'EXT', 'X', 'x' only for the last set of digits. So not (559) 559 EXt5591 EXT123

Now I have wrote the following but I do not know enough about Regex to optimize it more and get the result i want.

`@"^(?=[0-9])([-.+ Ee Xx Tt \s()0-9])+$"`

Comment: Perhaps you should let the field be free and live happy

Comment: I wish I could trust the clients that much :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
/^
(
(?:
    (?:^\+)               # matches the "+" sign at the beginning
  |
    (?:\(\d+\))           # matches '(' and its paired ')' but allows only digit inside
  |
    \d                    # matches a digit
  |
    [ .-]                 # matches a separator character
  |
    (?:(?>ext|x)\d{3}$)   # matches the EXT' part at the end
)+
)
$/ix
```

An example at: https://regex101.com/r/nC2vV4/1

Comment: Hi @Tiller, Thanks for the comment. Does this work for . net Regex also?

Comment: I'm sorry I've never touched .Net ; However AFAIK it should. The only touchy thing I see that could fail is my "(?>...)" which you would just have to replace by "(?:...)" if so.

Comment: I think it 'd be something like: `@"(?i)^((?:(?:^\+)|(?:\(\d+\))|\d|[ .-]|(?:(?>ext|x)\d{3}$))+)$"`

Comment: Weird, I'm using http://regexhero.net/tester/ and I canb't match anything. There must be something that .net doesn't like.

Comment: Everything works just fine for me on your website. Depending on what you're testing, you might want to activate the multiline-mode on the right side of your website.

Comment: Wait I think your second comment is good.. The Tester worked when i changed it to the LF delimited rather than CRLF